# Undefined symbol XXX first referenced

Tags: c++

i am using unix to test my cpp code. and it keep has this error.

Undefined symbol coffeeShop::~coffeeShop()  coffeeShop::coffeeShop() first referenced in file /var/tmp//ccvhyGI4.o /var/tmp//ccvhyGI4.o

coffeeShop::analysisFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)    /var/tmp//ccwBzN3b.o

and i think the problem is in the analysisfile... so here is it.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include "coffeeShop.h"
#include "order.h"
#include "orderNode.h"
#include "customer.h"
#include "myEvent.h"
#include "openEvent.h"
#include "closeEvent.h"
#include "arrivalEvent.h"
#include "startServiceEvent.h"
#include "completeServiceEvent.h"
using namespace std;

coffeeShop::coffeeShop(){
    rugTst = 0;
    rugTwt = 0;
    expTst = 0;
    expTwt = 0;
    rugNum=0;
    expNum=0;
    curTime = 1;
    rugTime = 1;
    expTime = 1;
    expressOpened=false;
    eventList = new GenericList();
    openList = new GenericList();
    closeList = new GenericList();
    COFFEE=new item("COFFEE", 2, true);
    TEA=new item("TEA", 3, true);
    DONUT=new item("DONUT", 1, true);
    ICEDCAPP=new item("ICEDCAPP", 6, false);
    BAGEL=new item("BAGEL", 4, true);
    PANINI=new item("PANINI", 12, false);
    custQueue=new myQueue();

}

coffeeShop::~coffeeShop(){
    delete COFFEE;
    delete TEA;
    delete DONUT;
    delete ICEDCAPP;
    delete BAGEL;
    delete PANINI;
    delete eventList;
    delete custQueue;
    delete openList;
    delete closeList;
}

void coffeeShop::analysisFile(string fileName){
    char* buf = new char[100];
    ifstream in(fileName, ios::in);
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in.getline(buf, 100);
        istringstream input(buf);
        string str = "";
        int time;
        input >> time;
        input >> str;
        if (str == "OPEN")
        {
            eo = new openEvent();
            eo->setTime(time);
            eventList->insert(eo);
            openList->insert(eo);
        }
        else if (str == "CLOSE")
        {
            ec = new closeEvent();
            ec->setTime(time);
            eventList->insert(ec);
            closeList->insert(ec);
        }
        else
        {
            string name;
            int num;
            customer* cust = new customer(time);
            while (input >> name&&input >> num)
            {
                cust->orderFood(new orderNode(createItem(name, num)));
            }
            custQueue->push(cust);
        }
    }
    eventNode* eoHead = openList->getHead();
    eventNode* ecHead = closeList->getHead();
    eo =(openEvent *) eoHead->node;
    ec =(closeEvent *)ecHead->node;
    while (!custQueue->isEmpty())
    {
        customer* c = custQueue->pop();
        if (rugTime > eo->beginTime)
        {
            if (eoHead->next)
            {
                eoHead = eoHead->next;
                eo = (openEvent *)eoHead->node;
            }
            expressOpened = true;
        }
        int time = c->getArriveTime();
        curTime = time;
        receiveCustomer(c, time);
        if (c->getArriveTime() > ec->beginTime)
        {
            if (ecHead->next)
            {
                ecHead = ecHead->next;
                ec = (closeEvent *)ecHead->node;
            }
            expressOpened = false;
        }
    }
    print();
}

void coffeeShop::print(){
    cout << "Simulation begins...\n" << endl;
    eventNode* temp = eventList->getHead();
    while (temp){
        temp->node->print();
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    summary();
}


order* coffeeShop::createItem(string name, int num)
{
    if (name == COFFEE->getName())
    {
        return new order(new item("COFFEE", 2, true), num);
    }
    else if (name == DONUT->getName())
    {
        return new order(new item("DONUT", 1, true), num);
    }
    else if (name == TEA->getName())
    {
        return new order(new item("TEA", 3, true), num);
    }
    else if (name == ICEDCAPP->getName())
    {
        return new order(new item("ICEDCAPP", 6, false), num);
    }
    else if (name == BAGEL->getName())
    {
        return new order(new item("BAGEL", 4, true), num);
    }
    else
    {
        return new order(new item("PANINI", 12, false), num);
    }
}

void coffeeShop::receiveCustomer(customer* cust,int time)
{
        eventList->insert(new arrivalEvent(time,cust));
        if (!expressOpened)
        {
            cust->setWaitTime(rugTime-time);
            rugTwt += cust->getWaitTime();
            curTime += cust->getWaitTime();
            eventList->insert(new startServiceEvent(curTime, cust, true));
            rugNum++;
            rugTst += cust->getServiceTime();
        }
        else
        {
            if (expressOpened&&expTime < rugTime)
            {

                if (expTime!=1)
                {
                    cust->setWaitTime(expTime - time);
                }
                else
                {
                    cust->setWaitTime(eo->beginTime - time);
                }
                expTwt += cust->getWaitTime();
                curTime += cust->getWaitTime();
                eventList->insert(new startServiceEvent(curTime, cust, false));
                expNum++;
                expTst += cust->getServiceTime();
            }
            else
            {
                cust->setWaitTime(rugTime - time);
                rugTwt += cust->getWaitTime();
                curTime += cust->getWaitTime();
                eventList->insert(new startServiceEvent(curTime, cust, true));
                rugNum++;
                rugTst += cust->getServiceTime();
            }
        }
        curTime += cust->getServiceTime();
        eventList->insert(new completeServiceEvent(curTime, cust));
        if (expressOpened&&expTime < rugTime)
        {
            expTime = curTime;
        }
        else
        {
            rugTime = curTime;
        }
}

void coffeeShop::summary(){
    cout << "...All Service complete.Final Summary :\n" << endl;
    cout << "Lane   Total       Total     Total      Average      Average\n" << endl;
    cout << "     Customers Service Time Wait Time Service Time Wait Time\n" << endl;
    cout << "Regular" << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(10) << rugNum << setw(10) << rugTst << setw(10) << rugTwt << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << (rugNum == 0 ? 0 : rugTst*1.0 / rugNum) << setw(10) << (rugNum == 0 ? 0 : rugTwt*1.0 / rugNum) << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Express" << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(10) << expNum << setw(10) << expTst << setw(10) << expTwt << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << (expNum == 0 ? 0 : expTst*1.0 / expNum) << setw(10) << (expNum == 0 ? 0 : expTwt*1.0 / expNum) << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "End of Processing" << endl;
}
```

and here is my header file

```
#include "myEvent.h"
#include "openEvent.h"
#include "closeEvent.h"
#include "GenericList.h"
#include "item.h"
#include "order.h"
#include "customer.h"
#include "myQueue.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class coffeeShop{
private:
    int rugNum;
    int expNum;
    int rugTst;
    int rugTwt;
    int expTst;
    int expTwt;
    int curTime;
    int rugTime;
    int expTime;
    bool expressOpened;
    GenericList* eventList;
    GenericList* openList;
    GenericList* closeList;
    openEvent* eo;
    closeEvent* ec;
    item* COFFEE;
    item* TEA;
    item* DONUT;
    item* ICEDCAPP;
    item* BAGEL;
    item* PANINI;
    myQueue* custQueue;
public:
    coffeeShop();
    ~coffeeShop();
    void analysisFile(string fileName);
    void print();
    order* createItem(string name,int num);
    void receiveCustomer(customer* cust,int time);
    void summary();
};
```

Comment: That's good - at least you tried creating an [mcve]. But add your class definition as well.

Comment: Did you declare it in a header file?

Comment: And you link with the "part of [your] code" that contains the constructor and destructor?

Comment: in the source file with the constructor/destructor did you #include the header?